# pointer & dereference

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, pointers, dereference

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct integer2{
    int* valuePtr;
    struct integer2* next;
};
typedef struct integer2* intpointer2;


int main() {

    int value2 = 5;
    int* dpointer = &value2;
    intpointer2 intPtr2 = (intpointer2)malloc(sizeof(struct integer2));
    //intPtr2->valuePtr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    printf("Version1\n");
    intPtr2->valuePtr = value2; //dereference
    printf("intPtr2->valuePtr address %p\n",&intPtr2->valuePtr);
    printf("intPtr2->valuePtr value: %d\n", intPtr2->valuePtr);
    //print 5
    printf("--------------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Version2\n");
    intPtr2->valuePtr = &value2;
    printf("intPtr2->valuePtr address %p\n",&intPtr2->valuePtr);
    printf("intPtr2->valuePtr value: %d\n", intPtr2->valuePtr);
    printf("intPtr2->valuePtr value: %d\n", (*intPtr2).valuePtr);
    //print 1834136
    printf("--------------------------------------------\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Hi, i have a question about pointer & dereference

In version#1, when I put `intPtr2->valuePtr = value2;`
I can print the value of 5

But in version#2, when I put `intPtr2->valuePtr = &value2;`
I print a weird output like 1834136

isn't valuePtr a pointer? I store the address of value2 should be not problem.
and in version#1, I only store the int, but I can print the value of 5.
I have no idea about this @@a

and one more question, what is the 1834136? it is an unsigned digits?

thank

Comment: `%d` is not the correct format specifier for a pointer.

Comment: no, I am trying to print the value of 5 in version2, but it isn't allow to do that.

Comment: In that case, you need to dereference it to get the value it's pointing to.

Comment: Your assignment of the value `5` to a the pointer member `intPtr2->valuePtr` is not correct. I'm fairly confident you wanted an address stored there; not a literal integral value. Your first `printf()` is printing the address *of* a pointer, not the address *in* the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use version 2. But:

```
printf("intPtr2->valuePtr address %p\n",&intPtr2->valuePtr);
printf("intPtr2->valuePtr value: %d\n", intPtr2->valuePtr);
```

The first line should be:

```
printf("intPtr2->valuePtr address %p\n",intPtr2->valuePtr);
```

Since `valuePtr` is already a pointer as you said, otherwise you're giving it the address of the pointer, which is not what you want. I'm pretty sure you want the address the pointer points to.

The second line should be:

```
printf("intPtr2->valuePtr value: %d\n", *intPtr2->valuePtr);
```

Since `intPtr2->valuePtr` is the pointer itself, but you still have to dereference it to get the actual int. Doing `(*intPtr2).valuePtr` is exactly what `intPtr2->valuePtr` does, `->` is short-hand for that syntax, so you'd still be left with the `valuePtr` pointer and would still have to dereference it.

Example: http://ideone.com/Fh8wwr

Comment: hmmm,ok... I have a another question on the first line, &inPtr->valuePtr is the address of valuePtr? and intPtr->valuePtr is the address of intPtr?

Comment: `&inPtr->valuePtr` is the address of `valuePtr` and `intPtr->valuePtr` is the pointer to (in your case returns the address of) `value2`, since that's what you set it to point to.